# pfSense DNS Resolver does not resolve local hostnames from DHCP static mappings

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp, pfsense, unbound

I'm on pfSense Community Edition 2.4.5-RELEASE-p1

I assigned some static DHCP mappings on one of my LAN interfaces

If I try to reach any one of those static mapped hosts by its Hostname (or by Client Id), pfSense does not resolve its IP address.

I understand I can solve this by enabling the DNS Forwarder and maybe using overrides but that doesn't look like the proper solution.

I didn't have this problem before switching to pfSense, when I was using a consumer device (Netgear R7000 all-in-1 router/firewall/switch/access point) but I guess it used `dnsmasq` internally, not `unbound` as the pfSense DNS Resolver does.

What should I change, either in pfSense or in the hosts configuration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under Services, DNS Resolver: scroll down and check "DHCP Registration" and "Static DHCP"

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me